# Proper way of doing SORT operation in iOS for multiple fields at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

This is my class

```
class Train {
   NSTimeInterval arrivalTime;
   NSTimeInterval estimatedTimeOfArrival;
}
```

I will have 10 objects of the class `Train` out of which, each objects are having proper `estimatedTimeOfArrival` value. But 3 objects has not proper values for `arrivalTime`.

My goal is to perform a SORT operation on the array of objects of this class.

So, what's the best way to achieve a SORT on both of the fields?

I am thinking to apply sort first on `arrivalTime` and then on `estimatedTimeOfArrival`.

This will make sense and good way of doing this stuff?

Comment: Lookup sortedArrayUsingComparator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I didn't have enough time to take a different turn. I ended up performing two sort operations on by one. And the data is what which I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a getter, which returns `arrivalTime` if it is set, and `estimatedTimeOfArrival` if not. Now, you can order your trains by the getter first and then on `estimatedTimeOfArrival`. This will avoid *strange* ordered elements in the list.